# Fixing Webpage in WebView according to screen width android

Tags: android, html, webview

Iam loading a webpage in my WebView. This WebPage has some text as well as some images. Currently, the text displays properly within the screen width. But the Image goes across the screen making me have to scroll horizontally in order to view the image.

I want the whole content of the Webpage to display to fit within the screen of the devices so that the user does not need to scroll horizontally.

Here is my code:-

```
    WebSettings webSettings =  webBody.getSettings();

    webSettings.setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setUseWideViewPort(true);
    webSettings.setDefaultZoom(ZoomDensity.FAR);
    webBody.loadDataWithBaseURL(null,newsBody, "text/html", "utf-8",null);
```

How can I go about it?

Answer (score 0):

In you html give image width to 100% like followin line.

src="images/ourservices.jpg" width="100%" height="100">

Comment: the html content comes from the server. I have no control over it